# Curl - Uploading an Excel file over FTPS

Tags: linux, bash, curl

As the title says, I need to automatically upload an excel file to a FTPS server.  Right now I'm using curl but if there is a better option out there, I'm all ears.

What I have so far:

```
curl -k --data-binary --ftp-ssl -T "/path/to/file.xlsx" ftp://user:pass@www.web.com
```

This will create an entry on the server but the Excel file will be blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this type of syntax:

```
curl -T /file/to/upload.xlsx  -u username:password ftps://ftpshost/
```

Comment: I ended up using `curl --cacert --ftp-ssl -T "file" -u user:pass ftp://site.com/`.  Close to what you gave me but with a few quirks.

Answer (score 0):

If your destination server is also linux I'd strongly recommend using scp.
If FTPs is the only transfer option you have, filezilla may be worth checking out.

Comment: I wish.  The other server is a windows server so I'm out of luck on that front.